# Digest verification failed for Reference

Tags: c#, cryptography, wif, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

I have implementation of a custom STS. After being authenticated and redirected but before the page was loaded I would receive this error:

```
[CryptographicException: Digest verification failed for Reference '#_8e0aea1a-713d-4536-8fac-a768073395e9'.]
```

The reference number would change every time I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found out that the claims, I had loaded from the database, had carriage return line feeds. Once I replaced those I had no more issues.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue and was able to resolve it using `LF (Unix)` newline separator when encoding the Base64.

Specifically, in our implementation, we require HTTP POST binding when submitting the SAML Response. The SAML Response is Base64-encoded and it fails when encoded using `CRLF (Windows)` newline separator. But when encode using `LF (Unix)`, it works. Also, the Character Set must be `UTF 8`.

This is the setting we use when encode using https://www.base64encode.org/ tool

[image]