# Digest verification failed

Tags: wif, adfs2.0, adfs

I'm developing a .NET web application which uses ADFS to manage users and logins. On my personal development machine and on our testing environment everything works fine. However, after publishing the application to the target production server I'm getting the following exception:

```
[CryptographicException: Digest verification failed for Reference '#_ed85954d-e2b3-44a1-a455-f13b8eca5756'.]
   System.IdentityModel.Reference.EnsureDigestValidityIfIdMatches(String id, Object resolvedXmlSource) +1124029
   System.IdentityModel.StandardSignedInfo.EnsureDigestValidityIfIdMatches(String id, Object resolvedXmlSource) +92
   System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.EnsureDigestValidity(String id, Object resolvedXmlSource) +33
   System.IdentityModel.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement() +240
   System.IdentityModel.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read() +107
   System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement() +52
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader) +1106
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader) +57
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ReadToken(XmlReader reader) +114
   System.IdentityModel.Services.TokenReceiver.ReadToken(String tokenXml, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas readerQuotas, FederationConfiguration federationConfiguration) +351
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase request) +387
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +103571
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

I've tried turning on WIF and WCF logging on the ADFS, but found nothing of interest in the logs.

I realize a very similar question has been created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013666/digest-verification-failed-for-reference), however my issue seems to be caused by something different as I'm not passing claims from a DB, only from the AD itself.

Another possibility is the one described in [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1430.windows-identity-foundation-wif-throws-exception-id6018-digest-verification-failed-for-reference.aspx) article... but I'm not using ISA server. If something else is changing the reply, I don't know how to find it.

I'm a bit out of ideas. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following recent XKCD comic is at least partially true:

[image: Second]

On the second page of Google results I came upon [this](http://setspn.blogspot.com/2010/08/some-isatmg-errors-with-resolution.html) blog post. The solution, as it turned out, was to uncheck the `Apply link translation` option in TMG for the ADFS machine.

It's a bit strange that IFD configured CRM servers (which also relied on this ADFS) worked without a hitch...