# Digest verfication failed for Reference

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I checked , [Digest verification failed for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013666/digest-verification-failed-for-reference) and 
[Digest verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009596/digest-verification-failed) and none of the answers fixed the issue for me.

I get the following error for 'some' O365 accounts and after deleting and recreating the account it goes away. Anyone has a clue ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue and after communicating with O365 team, it was identified some special characters on o365 account which caused it .In our case the display names of the account had a & character and it was ok after we removed it. But this started happening suddenly and O365 does not advice against having special characters on display names. I believe MS team is still looking into this.